# Convert string to decimal but have swedish currency

Tags: c#, parsing, decimal

My code:

```
        public decimal SetHourRate(string hourrate)
        {
            var value = decimal.Parse(hourrate, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat);            
            return value;
        }
```

In parameter:

```
string hourrate = "800.00"
```

My problem:
Right now my output is like `var value = 80000`? I want it to be like the string I put in. I'm from Sweden and we have a dot instead of comma to separate the decimals in currency. It must work even if the string look like this `string hourrate = "1050.67"`.

It's ok if the output will be like `var value = "800,00"` or `var value ="1050,67"`(comma instead of dot.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is returning the `80000` because the `.` in the swedish is the GroupSeparator. The `,` is the decimal separator.

You are passing a string like `800.00` so, `.` will be used as group separator. That is the reason you are getting this value.

You could force the decimal separator to be `.` chaging the a formater (CultureInfo), for sample:

```
public decimal SetHourRate(string hourrate)
{
    var swedishCulture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
    swedishCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

    var value = decimal.Parse(hourrate, NumberStyles.Currency, swedishCulture);
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use CultureInfo to specify what formatting to use when parsing.

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
decimal value;
if (decimal.TryParse(hourrate, NumberStyles.Currency, culture, out value))
{
    // Do what you want with value if successfully parsed
}
else
{
    // Failed to parse
}
```

Make sure you include `System.Globalization` at the top of your code.